# How can I get tracks from another iTunes library onto my iPhone without wiping it?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I got  a bunch of audiobooks on a different Mac then my own (to which I don't have access at the present moment). I want to get them onto my iPhone without erasing stuff from my iPhone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoodReader for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-iphone/id306277111?mt=8) ($5) will let you load files directly to your iPhone over your LAN and play them from there. That should work fine if your audiobooks are a) all one file (if they are in multiple files there may not be 'playlist' support, which would be annoying, and b) not DRM'd. If they are DRM'd you'll need to sync them via iTunes or, in the case of Audible.com, you can download them from the [Audible player](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audible/id379693831?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

Copy the files from the iTunes Library where the files can be found to the Library that your iPhone is synced to and sync your iPhone.

You can add files to an iTunes Library by going to the top-left and clicking 'add file to library'

Comment: I can't do that since I don't have access to the computer containing the library I normally sync to.